# Carregar dinamicamente conteudo atraves da tag <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, select

Estou com uma dúvida e gostaria que pudesse me ajudar.
Meu caso é o seguinte tenho um  dinâmico onde de acordo com a opção selecionada ele retorna um JSON com as informações das Unidades de Hoteis.

O que preciso é de preencher no HTML o conteudo do JSON de acordo com a opcao selecionado do select.

Segue o link do codeshare para explicacao melhor do código.
https://codeshare.io/pulisnoob

Comment: conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não consegui entender direito sua pergunta, porém baseado na minha experiência o que eu faço normalmente quando preciso carregar conteúdo dinâmico de acordo com um input do tipo select é o seguinte:

Eu crio uma tag script do tipo text/template

```
<script type="text/template" id="templateDoConteudo">
    <div>
        <h1>{{titulo}}</h1>
        <span>{{texto}}</span>
    </div>    
</script>
```

Crio um evento que irá observar o meu input de select

```
$('select#idDoCampo').on('change', function (){
    // Esse código garante que o template só será preenchido após o
    // json ser recuperado.
    $.when(buscarJSON($(this).val()))
    .then(preencheTemplate);
});
```

Crio a função que irá buscar o json de acordo com o que foi selecionado

```
function buscarJSON(id) {
    // retorna a promisse do jquery para a função then();
    // esse ajax pode ser facilmente substituido por outras promisses
    // do jquery ($.Deferred(), $.getJson, etc...).
    return $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'pesquisa.php'
         dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

E crio uma função que vai fazer o preenchimento e append do template na página

```
    function preencheTemplate(valor) {
        // recupero o conteúdo do template
        var template = $('script[type="text/template"]#templateDoConteudo').html();
        // substituo os marcadores utilizando expressões regulares
        template = template.replace(/{{titulo}}/g, valor.titulo)
                           .replace(/{{texto}}/g, valor.texto);
        // insiro o conteúdo novo no container
        $('div#container').append(template);
    }
```

Caso o seu JSON tenha um Array é só colocar um foreach (ou $.each()) na função preencheTemplate() e tratar o resultado apropriadamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado Raphael consegui resolver.

Comment: Se você utilizou minha resposta você poderia marca-la como certa por favor? Caso você tenha resolvido sozinho de alguma outra forma seria interessante você escrever uma resposta e aceitar ela para que pessoas com problemas parecidos possam consultar também. =)